# Plugin org.eclipse.ui.ide.nl_ru

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Where can I find sources and available versions of plugin org.eclipse.ui.ide.nl_ru?

Google does not know anything on this topic and gives me only 2 result lines on request: "org.eclipse.ui.ide.nl_ru".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.eclipse.ui.ide.nl_ru` is a fragment containing the **Russian language pack** for the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin.

The [**Eclipse Babel project**](https://www.eclipse.org/babel/) provides the language packs for the [Eclipse project](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/) and for other projects.

The [language packs for the **Eclipse 2020-06** release can be found here](https://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.19.0/2021-06/2021-06.php#ru) and the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.nl_ru` fragment is contained in [`BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-ru_4.20.0.v20210630020001.zip`](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.19.0/2021-06/BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-ru_4.20.0.v20210630020001.zip) (`...-eclipse-...` means Eclipse project, the Eclipse platform and the Eclipse Java development tools (JDT)).